# Vapor 3: transform array of Future object to an array of Future other objects

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

I tried to make the most basic example that I could think of for my problem. I have a `Course` model and a many-to-many table to `User` that also stores some extra properties (the `progress` in the example below).

```swift
import FluentPostgreSQL
import Vapor

final class Course: Codable, PostgreSQLModel {
  var id: Int?
  var name: String
  var teacherId: User.ID

  var teacher: Parent<Course, User> {
    return parent(\.teacherId)
  }

  init(name: String, teacherId: User.ID) {
    self.name = name
    self.teacherId = teacherId
  }
}

struct CourseUser: Pivot, PostgreSQLModel {
  typealias Left = Course
  typealias Right = User

  static var leftIDKey: LeftIDKey = \.courseID
  static var rightIDKey: RightIDKey = \.userID

  var id: Int?
  var courseID: Int
  var userID: UUID
  var progress: Int

  var user: Parent<CourseUser, User> {
    return parent(\.userID)
  }
}
```

Now, when I return a `Course` object, I want the JSON output to be something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Course 1",
  "teacher": {"name": "Mr. Teacher"},
  "students": [
    {"user": {"name": "Student 1"}, progress: 10},
    {"user": {"name": "Student 2"}, progress: 60},
  ]
}
```

Instead of what I would normally get, which is this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Course 1",
  "teacherID": 1,
}
```

So I created some extra models and a function to translate between them:

```swift
struct PublicCourseData: Content {
  var id: Int?
  let name: String
  let teacher: User
  let students: [Student]?
}

struct Student: Content {
  let user: User
  let progress: Int
}

extension Course {
  func convertToPublicCourseData(req: Request) throws -> Future<PublicCourseData> {
    let teacherQuery = self.teacher.get(on: req)
    let studentsQuery = try CourseUser.query(on: req).filter(\.courseID == self.requireID()).all()

    return map(to: PublicCourseData.self, teacherQuery, studentsQuery) { (teacher, students) in
      return try PublicCourseData(id: self.requireID(),
                                  name: self.name,
                                  teacher: teacher,
                                  students: nil) // <- students is the wrong type!
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I am *almost* there, but I am not able to convert `studentsQuery` from `EventLoopFuture<[CourseUser]>` to `EventLoopFuture<[Student]>`. I tried multiple combinations of `map` and `flatMap`, but I can't figure out how to translate an array of Futures to an array of different Futures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic you're looking for will look like this

```swift
extension Course {
    func convertToPublicCourseData(req: Request) throws -> Future<PublicCourseData> {
        return teacher.get(on: req).flatMap { teacher in
            return try CourseUser.query(on: req)
                                 .filter(\.courseID == self.requireID())
                                 .all().flatMap { courseUsers in
                // here we should query a user for each courseUser
                // and only then convert all of them into PublicCourseData
                // but it will execute a lot of queries and it's not a good idea
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you to use the [SwifQL lib](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/SwifQL) instead to build a custom query to get needed data in one request

You could mix Fluent's queries with SwifQL's in case if you want to get only one course, so you'll get it in 2 requests:

```swift
struct Student: Content {
    let name: String
    let progress: Int
}

extension Course {
    func convertToPublicCourseData(req: Request) throws -> Future<PublicCourseData> {
        return teacher.get(on: req).flatMap { teacher in
            // we could use SwifQL here to query students in one request
            return SwifQL.select(\CourseUser.progress, \User.name)
                        .from(CourseUser.table)
                        .join(.inner, User.table, on: \CourseUser.userID == \User.id)
                        .execute(on: req, as: .psql)
                        .all(decoding: Student.self).map { students in
                return try PublicCourseData(id: self.requireID(),
                                          name: self.name,
                                          teacher: teacher,
                                          students: students)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get a list of courses in one request you could use pure `SwifQL` query.

I simplified desired JSON a little bit

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Course 1",
  "teacher": {"name": "Mr. Teacher"},
  "students": [
    {"name": "Student 1", progress: 10},
    {"name": "Student 2", progress: 60},
  ]
}
```

first of all let's create a model to be able to decode query result into it

```swift
struct CoursePublic: Content {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    struct Teacher:: Codable {
        let name: String
    }
    let teacher: Teacher
    struct Student:: Codable {
        let name: String
        let progress: Int
    }
    let students: [Student]
}
```

Ok now we are ready to build a custom query. Let's build it in some request handler function

```swift
func getCourses(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[CoursePublic]> {
    /// create an alias for student
    let s = User.as("student")

    /// build a PostgreSQL's json object for student
    let studentObject = PgJsonObject()
        .field(key: "name", value: s~\.name)
        .field(key: "progress", value: \CourseUser.progress)

    /// Build students subquery
    let studentsSubQuery = SwifQL
        .select(Fn.coalesce(Fn.jsonb_agg(studentObject),
                            PgArray(emptyMode: .dollar) => .jsonb))
        .from(s.table)
        .where(s~\.id == \CourseUser.userID)


    /// Finally build the whole query
    let query = SwifQLSelectBuilder()
        .select(\Course.id, \Course.name)
        .select(Fn.to_jsonb(User.table) => "teacher")
        .select(|studentsSubQuery| => "students")
        .from(User.table)
        .join(.inner, User.table, on: \Course.teacherId == \User.id)
        .join(.leftOuter, CourseUser.table, on: \CourseUser.teacherId == \User.id)
        .build()
    /// this way you could print raw query
    /// to execute it in postgres manually
    /// for debugging purposes (e.g. in Postico app)
    print("raw query: " + query.prepare(.psql).plain)
    /// executes query with postgres dialect
    return query.execute(on: req, as: .psql)
        /// requests an array of results (or use .first if you need only one first row)
        /// You also could decode query results into the custom struct
        .all(decoding: CoursePublic.self)
}
```

Hope it will help you. There may be some mistakes in the query cause I wrote it without checking  You can try to print a raw query to copy it and execute in e.g. Postico app in postgres directly to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Also if you're in Discord you could find me as iMike#3049 I'll help you with your query. After that I'll fix my answer here.

Comment: Surely there must be a way to map EventLoopFuture<[CourseUser]> to EventLoopFuture<[Student]>, without diving into SwifQL and custom queries? Even if that might be the most optimal thing to do, for now I am really simply wondering how to map that one array to the other, to be honest. I am not quite ready yet to also introduce SwiftQL on top of everything else I am learning at the same time :)

Comment: then just do `.map { courseUsers in return courseUsers.map { courseUser in return Student.init(...initialize it here...) } }`

Comment: Yep, I tried stuff like that, but it just doesn't work :( 
Either I get a bunch of compiler errors, or I can't fetch the user object that belongs to CourseUser, since that's a Future as well and at that point I am working with normal non-Future objects, etc. Such a mess! So yes I get why using SwifQL will be better but it just frustrates me to no end that this isn't working :)